# Why does Xcode insist on having (id) as method parameter?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

My method declaration in the interface:

```
-(void)doSomethingOnGrass:(Grass*)grass;
```

While writing the implementation, Xcode's autocomplete feature tends to put this:

```
-(void)doSomethingOnGrass:(id)grass {

}
```

Xcode changed the parameter type to `id`.I realize that I can get it working with `id` anyway, but I'm not really sure what's the point of changing the parameter type in this scenario. What is it?

Xcode 4.3.2.

Comment: Your declaration and implementation don't match. What's up with that?

Comment: Do you need to include Grass.h?

Comment: @DrummerB: Lol! Sorry, accident. There :)

Comment: @GrahamPerks: Do I need to? Well, I believe I do (I'm doing it). Why?

Comment: Did you try cleaning your project?

Comment: @DrummerB: It keeps on happening.

Comment: @GrahamPerks: If it helps, I import Grass.h only in the interface but not in the implementation.

Comment: @Omega Might be that Xcode get's that wrong, with the indirect implementation. This seems to be a bug. You can report this to apple, or just change it, because there are good chances you will never hear from them ;)